# Connecting to JBoss 7.1.1 MBean remotely

Tags: java, jboss, remote-access, jmx, jconsole

After implementing a MBean in our project (deployed on a JBoss AS 7.1.1 in standalone mode), I've performed some testing using JConsole and creating a "Local Process" connection (the one that uses the JBoss PID) and this worked fine. The MBean can be seen, reached and returns the expected value. However I am not able to connect using the "Remote Process".

[image: JConsole new connection screen]

This is the JMX subsystem configuration:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
        <show-model value="true"/>
        <remoting-connector use-management-endpoint="true"/>
    </subsystem>
```

And this is the socket configuration:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
    <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9995}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
    <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
    <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
    <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
    <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
    <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
    <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
    <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
    <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
        <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
    </outbound-socket-binding>
</socket-binding-group>
```

I've found several *tastes* for the URL to use in there, but I've tried them with the different suggested ports (9990, 9995, 1090, 4447) without success:

- service:jmx:remoting-jmx://127.0.0.1:9995
- service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:9995/jmxrmi

The error doesn't bring much information and says "The connection to ... did not succeed"

I've configured my JBoss according to the information found here:

- https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/UsingJconsoleToConnectToJMXOnAS7
- https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JMX+subsystem+configuration

I think I have the correct configuration for JBoss 7.1.1 and then the port should be the 'management-native' one (9995), but there has to be something missing in here. Does anyone knows what could be?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your port configuration, the **service:jmx:remoting-jmx://127.0.0.1:9995** URL works for me, with:

1. Use <jboss-home>/bin/jconsole.sh  (or bat) to launch jconsole. This includes the required classpath.
2. Make sure your **JBOSS_HOME** env var is correctly set. I run a couple of different versions and got burned by this.
3. You need to use a valid management user and password. Not using those credentials (or invalid ones) gives you the same non-obvious error messages.

So when using **remoting-jmx**, the target port should be the one defined in **<socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9995}"/>**

As I understand it, when using **http-remoting-jmx**, the target port should be the one defined in **<socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>** but I have *never* been able to get this to work.

I'm not completely sold on these new protocols, so I frequently deploy a [JMXMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19698-01/816-7609/connectors-116/index.html) ConnectionServer.... problem solved.

Comment: Using the <jboss-home>/bin/jconsole.sh to launch the jconsole was what I was missing! I was using the JDK JConsole all the time... Thank you very, very much!